# Angular post request sending data to server

Tags: angular, http, header

I am trying to send data to a server, but it's just not getting there

```
 signUp(email: string, password: string) {
    let data = { email, password };
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    });

    console.log('Requesting', email, password);
    return this.http.post(this.sellerApi, data, { responseType: 'text', headers });
  }

  this.api.signUp(email, password).subscribe( r => console.log(r));
```

I print the request on the server but it' empty

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: Do you actually `subscribe` to this request? You have to if you want to invoke it...

Comment: @miselking I do, I updated the post, so you can fully see what I am doing

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools (Network tab)? Also, any console errors?

Comment: @Maryannah I updated it, that's  everything I am doing

Comment: @mbojko here it is https://pastebin.com/RYM2DW8w

Comment: Judging from that, the request _is_ going out properly, and the problem is server-side.

Comment: @mbojko I couldn't see why, the php file is called and all I do is print the request to a log file, except it's empty

Comment: It's just writing the request to a text file

Comment: I assume you know that $_POST won’t work right? You’ll need $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: I just read that, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Angular `http.post` returns an `Observable` of the result from the server. You must subscribe to the observable with a target function for what you wish to do with the result (and any error).

Answer (score 1):

you need to `import HttpClientModule from '@angular/common/http'` in your `app.module.ts` at first.then you need to inject httpClient dependency in your component `constructor(DI)` like this one:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  signUp(email: string, password: string) {
    let data = { email, password };
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    console.log('Requesting', email, password);
    return this.http.post(this.sellerApi, data, { responseType: 'text', headers : headers });
  }

  testApi() {
    this.signUp(email, password).subscribe(r => console.log(r));
  }
```

Comment: I did that, the request goes through, it was application/json that didn't work.

Comment: I changed, it to application/x-www-form-urlencode but now the data is weirdly json encoded. Instead of $_POST having the fields, it has the entire json string as a key

Comment: so  just delete headers it's not needed in your case try this:
 return this.http.post(this.sellerApi, data);

Comment: removed, Now it's empty again

Comment: please make sure your response code is 200 and ok in your browser tab network xhr 's or send a screenshot from that in your question.

Comment: can I see your backend script??